# Is bashrc used to find java when running a java program from a script using ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

We need to run java program on a server 2 from a script which is on server 1 via ssh. When I login to server 2 and run the java program, it works. 
However, when I try to trigger the java program from server 1 by using ssh, it throws java not found exception.

The java path is present in the bashrc file on server 2(/home/java/jdk_1.7/bin/java) and 'which java' on server 2 shows this path as well which explains why directly triggering the program on server 2 works.
Is there any other file besides bashrc where java path should be present so that java is detected when invoked from a script from a different server

Adding the relevant parts of the code
Script on server 1

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_CLASS = “com.appStarter.main”
JAVA_CONFIG = “$PATH:/home/java/java_1.6/bin” ($PATH on this box has /app/java/jdk_170_100_64/bin) 
USER_NAME= sudoUserName
START_COMMAND = java $MAIN_CLASS $USER_NAME
eval “$START_COMMAND”
```

The invokes a java program which ssh into server 2. Below are excerpts from this java program

```
public String ssh(String host, String command)
   String ssh = “/usr/bin/ssh”
   String result = triggerCommand(ssh, “-a”, host, command)
   return result;
}
public String triggerCommand(final String… command){
   ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
   Process process = processBuilder.start();
   InputStream iS = process.getInputSteam();
   Reader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));

   String output=””;
…output will contain the output from the reader
}
```

In the above class, host is 2 and command is an unix command like startComponent.sh shown below

```
#!usr/bin/ksh
MAIN_CLASS = “com.componentStarter.main”
START_COMMAND = java $MAIN_CLASS 
eval “$START_COMMAND”
```

Our bash_profile and profile includes bashrc as below and sets the path as shown

```
if  [  if ~/.bashrc ]; then
          . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH = $PATH (where $PATH includes /app/java/jdk170_5-64b/bin)
EXPORT PATH
```

Comment: You have to show the exact command you use, or it's very hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: copy codes from bashrc to your script

Comment: Modifications to `PATH` should be in `.bash_profile`, so that they are made in a login shell. Any other shell invoked from the login shell inherits the modified path via the environment.

Comment: Have added additional details in the question. Our bash_profile includes the java path as well as shown in the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Are you sshing as root or as user? If u ssh as user and sudo afterwards, check your path via "sudo -s" or "sudo -i" 
If it returns the wrong path variables, add it to a custom visudo file
like for example in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Comment: We ssh as root while invoking the script

Comment: Why is your startComponent.sh invoked with ksh? I guess .bashrc only works for bash

Comment: java path is also added in profile, bash_profile and bashrc, so even ksh should get the correct path